# Flask - Error werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError -

Tags: python, json, flask, werkzeug

I am trying to run my first flask app, but I am getting the following error after sending the POST request on Postman.

*Error:
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'goal'*

The error is probably coming from here: `goal = request.form['goal']` , I have already tried changing the `request.form` to `request.json`or `form.get` without success. :(

Any ideas?

Note: I am using Windows, Visual Studio, Python 3.9 and Postman.

````
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/create', methods=('GET', 'POST'))

def create():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        goal = request.form['goal']
        content = request.form.get['content']
        
        if not title:
            flash('Goal is required!')
    return calc(goal,content)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run(debug=True)

def calc(goal, content):

#rest of the code here...#

    return jsonify({
        "status": 200,
        "message": "Success",
        "data":data
})```
````

Comment: I find it very useful in cases like this to add a print(request) at the start of your `create()` function. That should show you what elements you have in the object and help you determine your next debugging steps.

Comment: Thanks for the input @JamesMcPherson , I've added the following lines after the create() function:

`print(request.method)
print(request.url)
print(request.data)
print(request.headers)`

The prints are:

_POST
http://127.0.0.1:5000/create
b''
None
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 4c3a-896f-yy8b-a82c-dxxx8c9xx (edited)
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0_

Being request.data "b''" and the Content-Length: 0 I assume that I need to adjust the app to receive the POST information properly.

Comment: It appears to me that you haven't created your initial base webpage (index.html), which would contain your form element. If you look at https://github.com/jmcp/find-my-electorate/blob/master/app.py#L271, you'll see that the base route calls `render_template()` with an argument, which is https://github.com/jmcp/find-my-electorate/blob/master/templates/index.html. That creates a <form> element which is passed to the POST method.

In your snippet you don't have anything like that, so there's no request object to pass at all.

Comment: Thanks for the help @JamesMcPherson, I was able to receive the POST information after creating the initial base webpage!                                                                                          I am trying to accept the answer, but I am not sure why it is not showing the check mark beside the answer/comment.

Comment: Probably because it's a comment rather than an Answer. I'll fix that right up. Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you haven't created your initial base webpage (index.html), which would contain your form element.

If you look at https://github.com/jmcp/find-my-electorate/blob/master/app.py#L271, you'll see that the base route calls `render_template()` with an argument, which is https://github.com/jmcp/find-my-electorate/blob/master/templates/index.html. That creates a  element which is passed to the POST method.

In your snippet you don't have anything like that, so there's no request object to pass at all.